# Flash player is not installing in samsung galaxy-s with 2.2

Tags: android, flash

I got a problem with the  adobe flashplayer 10.1 installation in my device. I am using samsung galaxy-S mobile and when I Installed the flash player and while clicking the flashplayer Icon in my device its showing "flasplayer not installed"

Is It the problem with my device or flash player

Help is always appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right, you can't have flash player on android 2:2

Comment: Thanks , but how can we play the audio with a webview on 2.2?